# Module Federation - webpack reads wrong dependency versions from package.json

Tags: angular, webpack, dependencies, webpack-module-federation

Inside my Module Federation setup I have a host application that consumes a few remote apps. They all share the angular framework dependencies as singletons. This is the host's webpack.config.json file:

```
new ModuleFederationPlugin({
  remotes: {
    mf1: "mf1@http://localhost:3000/remoteEntry.js",
    buy: 'buy@http://localhost:3002/remoteEntry.js',
    logo: 'logo@http://localhost:3003/remoteEntry.js'
  },

  shared: {
    "@angular/core": { singleton: true, },
    "@angular/common": { singleton: true, },
    "@angular/router": { singleton: true, },
  },
}),
```

Inside both the host's and remote's `package.json` the Angular versions are defined as `^11.0.0`. The actual versions installed are: host: `11.0.0`, remote: `11.0.9.`.
Bow because of the definition inside `package.json` and the actual versions being compatible according to semantic versioning, I expected webpack to just load the highest compatible Angular version (i.e. `11.0.9`) once. Instead I'm getting a warning saying `Unsatisfied version 11.0.9 of shared singleton module @angular/core (required =11.0.0)`. Whare does `=11.0.0` come from? Why doesn't recognize webpack that the versions should be compatible?

Answer (score 2):

I would really specify the `requiredVersion` in the plugin configuration and not rely on just having it read from your `package.json`. The issue is it will not just read your root
`package.json`, it will also read the `package.json` of any modules you are using from your `node_modules` that themselves also require/import `@angular/core`. This means you will end up with an actual shared "manifest" that includes many different potential version ranges, which can cause the sort of errors you are seeing.